# Why is this program not drawing the square?

Tags: java, swing

I am currently learning out of Computing Concepts with java 2 essentials by Cay Hortmans,
And i copied this program straight from the book, yet it is not working. Im not looking for an entirely separate way of doing this, but just why this code, straight from the book, is not drawing the square correctly.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ColorSelect extends Applet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7954365679431207534L;

    public void init(){
        String input; //ask the user for red, green, blue values

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Red:");
        float red = Float.parseFloat(input);

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Green:");
        float green = Float.parseFloat(input);

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Blue:");
        float blue = Float.parseFloat(input);
        fillColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        final int SQUARE_LENGTH = 100;

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        //select color into graphics content

        g2.setColor(fillColor);

        //construct and fill a square whose center is the center of the window

        Rectangle square = new Rectangle(
                (getWidth() - SQUARE_LENGTH) / 2,
                (getHeight() -  SQUARE_LENGTH) / 2,
                SQUARE_LENGTH,
                SQUARE_LENGTH);

        g2.fill(square);
    }
    private Color fillColor;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *not drawing the square correctly*? Do you get an error or it draws the square in an undesirable way?

Comment: @Christian it doesnt draw the square at all

Comment: What does `getWidth` and `getHeight` return?

Comment: I get an error when I input the values for RGB, but if I manually assign a color to `fillColor` it draws the square correctly.

Comment: @JoshM as far as i have read it just returns the size of the applet window-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `r`, `g`, `b` values are all `float`s, you are invoking the `Color` constructor that has 3 `float` parameters: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(float, float, float)

> Creates an opaque sRGB color with the specified red, green, and blue values in the range (0.0 - 1.0). Alpha is defaulted to 1.0. The actual color used in rendering depends on finding the best match given the color space available for a particular output device.

Either change your `r, g, b` types to `int` or cast to `int`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, i realized when imputing i was using int values rather then floats, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle specifies bounds of two opposite corners just as fill() wants. You need

```
Rectangle square = new Rectangle(
                                  (getWidth()/2 - SQUARE_LENGTH/2),
                                  (getHeight()/2 -  SQUARE_LENGTH/2),
                                  (getWidth()/2 + SQUARE_LENGTH/2),
                                  (getHeight()/2 +  SQUARE_LENGTH/2)
                                );
```

Comment: Warning: Can't read AppletViewer properties file: \\*Private*Using defaults.
Can't save user properties file: \\fwusdpubprof\fwhs\Profiles\webprg7\students\.appletviewer
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Red Green Blue
 at java.awt.Color.testColorValueRange(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Color.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Color.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Color.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at ColorSelect.init(ColorSelect.java:20)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)